# django press Enter and it show ^M

Tags: python, django

I want to change my models in django

when I execute `python manage.py makemigrations` ,it asks a question:

> Did you rename the demoapp.Myblog model to Blog? [y/N] y^M^M^M

that I input **y** and press Enter,but it adds **^M** to the line

I've looked around and apparently but I've got no choices

can anybody tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Better to reset the console frequently.
This is not a big problem but due to multiple terminals being not reset for long durations, such problem occurs.

Comment: Thanks ,but this problem only occurs when I execute the django-command，and I try to execute other command such as apt-get install xxx, and press Enter, it works well

Comment: after I reboot my system ,everything  is  OK, 
That's queer indeed

Comment: `exec $SHELL` does not work - had to close window and reopen terminal

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this may happen if [your terminal isn't configured correctly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441744/pressing-enter-produces-m-instead-of-a-newline), and incorrectly interprets newlines. If you're not running on ubuntu, google for the operating system and/or terminal application you're using, with the term `ctrl+m`. ^ is often displayed when you press control and some key. I'm not sure about the technical details, buy I often see `^c` after stopping an application with CTRL+c.